# Ruby rescue-like syntax

Tags: ruby

I would like to implement something with a rescue-like syntax.

```
begin
 raise "Failed"
rescue Exception => e
 puts e
end
```

This works, and e is assigned to the corresponding value. But used in a method, this will raise an exception saying that e is undefined. In other words, how can rescue assigns something to e this way without throwing an undefined error?

```
class MyClass
  def to_s
    "hello"
  end
end

def my_method
  puts e.to_s
end

my_method(MyClass => e)

#=> undefined local variable or method `e' for main:Object
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just pass MyClass as a parameter?

Comment: In fact, I just want to know how rescue works... :-)

Comment: It's a syntactic construct, part of the lex/parse process. You'd have to change the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps what you are looking for is:

```
class MyClass
  def self.hello
    puts "This is a class method."
  end
  def bye
    puts "This is an instance method."
  end
end

def my_method(params)
  klass = params[:class]
  puts klass.hello   # Call a class method
  inst = klass.new   # Create an instance
  puts inst.bye      # Call an instance method
end 

my_method(:class => MyClass)
```

Three things to note:

- Although the `rescue` syntax and the "named parameter" syntax look the same, all they have in common is the `=>` operator. In the first case, you are telling to `rescue` the `Exception` "into" the variable `e`, effectively storing it in that variable. In the second case, you are telling Ruby to collect all parameters passed to the method and store them in a hash, using the supplied key/value pairs. Effectively, you are storing `MyClass` in the `params` hash, under the key `:class`.
- In your above example, the `to_s` definition will not be callable on `MyClass` itself, because you defined it as an instance method. Instance methods are only available when you create an "instance" of the class with `inst = MyClass.new`. Then, you can call `inst.to_s`. Think of the class as an abstract "type" of thing, and of the instance as a concrete thing of that type. If you want the method to be available on the class, not the instances, you need to prefix it with `self.` I have illustrated the two different syntaxes above.
- Again in your example, you are using `def MyClass`, which Ruby will interpret as "define a method with the name `MyClass`". If you want to define a class, you need to use `class MyClass` instead.

Hope this clarifies things a bit.

Comment: Based on what you said, i.e. "In the first case, you are telling to rescue the Exception "into" the variable e, effectively storing it in that variable.", is it be possible to reproduce that exact same feature?

Comment: As others have commented, no, this is not possible. That's what method parameters - regular or "named" - are for! Having a method rely on parameters that aren't defined inside the method definition is asking for trouble. I guess that's why I don't know of any language that supports it :-)