# What's the syntax (=>) used in assign error object to variable of `rescue` method?

Tags: ruby, variables, syntax, raise, hashrocket

The `rescue` which could assigns a variable to reference the error object has this syntax (`=>`)

```
rescue => e
```

If `rescue` is the one of the general method call, what's the meaning of `=>`.
Could I use the same syntax on other method call?

```
my_method arg1, arg2 => my_obj
```

Comment: No, it's a syntactic construct. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669128/ruby-rescue-like-syntax#comment12281753_9669128, I wonder why this is being asked all of a sudden.

Comment: @DaveNewton It appeared in [RubyTapas](http://devblog.avdi.org/2013/02/25/rubytapas-freebie-caller-specified-fallback-handler/).

Comment: @mockturtl A year and a half ago? And if someone subscribed to tapas I'd actually assume they'd know how to find the answer out on their own, but I'm overly-optimistic at times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While [`raise` is indeed a method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-raise), `rescue` is not. It is a keyword and defined on [parse.y:10467](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/parse.y#L10467). As such, the syntax you have is special to `rescue` (since `=> e` isn't any sort of *method* argument), and not valid for methods themselves (at least not with the same meaning). How/where the `rescue => e` syntax itself is defined in the parser I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 4):

As some football coach/philosopher-king might say, it is what it is. Here's Ruby's [parse.y](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y). Of particular interest is [this part](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/08d81f26833a7741eb85525d0e8f641f8b8a53b6/parse.y#L3827-3873):

```
opt_rescue      : keyword_rescue exc_list exc_var then
                  compstmt
                  opt_rescue
                    ...
                | none
                ;

exc_list        : arg_value
                    ...
                | mrhs
                    ...
                | none
                ;

exc_var         : tASSOC lhs
                    ...
                | none
                ;
```

**Explanation**
`exc_list` basically allows nothing, an exception type, or a (splatted) series of exceptions like `rescue ZeroDivisionError, LoadError`

`exc_var` can be nothing or `=> some_variable`

`opt_rescue` can therefore be `rescue` by itself or plus either or both of the above.

It's *only* listed here as special syntax for assignment for exceptions. The only other use for `=>` is for [key-value association](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/08d81f26833a7741eb85525d0e8f641f8b8a53b6/parse.y#L4902-4918).

Note also that `arg_value` and `mrhs` are on the left-hand side and `lhs` is on the right-hand side, which is as far as I can tell the only place where this occurs. Someone correct me if I'm wrong here, but there isn't any other "backwards" assignment in parse.y.

Comment: Gah I went over all that and somehow missed `exc_var`. Good find.

Answer (score 0):

No, the syntax in the rescue is only used there.  If you use the hash rocket '=>' in a function call like that, it will be interpreted as a hash, and if arg2 was not defined as a variable previously, it will be an error.

```
def foo(a,b)
  puts b.inspect
end

foo "bar", :baz => 5   #=> {:baz=>5}

foo "bar", baz => 5    #=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `baz'

baz = "flux"

foo "bar", baz => 5   #=> {"flux"=>5}
```